# How can I filter google map marker using jQuery and json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I want to put markers which satisfy conditions I set before.

So I did

```
$.get("/map/getspot", function(data, status){
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ 
        if (data[i].name == "hello") {
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    title:data[i].name,
                    map: map
           });
           marker.setMap(map);
        }
     }
});
```

In map/getspot, I have

```
[{"id":1,"name":"hello","lat":37.552021,"lng":126.935887,"spot_description":"haho","address":"help","created_at":"2015-08-01T07:23:28.645Z","updated_at":"2015-08-01T07:23:28.645Z"}]
```

I rendered it.
But the problem is, it doesn't work.

It works well(puts all markers on my map) when I erase

```
if(data[i].name == "hello")
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/u9Lgh9ta/ So `console.log(data[i].name)` your data to examine it closer.

Comment: @IvanJovovic OMG Yeah! My marker also works well! I changed "hello" to 'hello' just " -> ', and it works! I think the problem comes from my IDE(Cloud9). Thank you for your checking also!